# how to get the URL of a google script webapp inside the webapp

Tags: url, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've a google script deployed as a webapp. This webapp needs to send email with the URL of the webapp so that the recipient can access the webapp using the URL. How can i get the URL within the webapp?

Comment: why don't you simply hard code it in the email's body ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` to get the URL of the published app in your code.

Comment: This only gives you the dev URL... not the prod URL.